# discord music bot - missing intents

Tags: python, discord, bots

The following block result in error:

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix ="?")
```

> TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'

The full code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

from help_cog import help_cog
from music_cog import music_cog

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix ="?")

bot.remove_command("help")

bot.add_cog(help_cog(bot))
bot.add_cog(music_cog(bot))
bot.run(os.getenv("token"))
```

I don't know how to fix it

Comment: dpy v2 requires intents to be defined and passed to the Bot constructor. I suggest you read their documentation and/or join the official support Discord. Also to note loading cogs and extensions is async now.
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html

Comment: I have given you an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()

# To define additional intents
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents=intents)
```

Since discord.py v2 you need to explicity define your intents and pass them to your Bot constructor https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html

You also have to enable privileged intents in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

In addition to this, many methods have become async, this includes loading extensions and cogs.
https://gist.github.com/Rapptz/6706e1c8f23ac27c98cee4dd985c8120

I suggest you give their docs a read-through, look at some of the examples on the official repo, and join the support Discord.